# Can an Illustrator file be saved as a PDF with layers without retaining the editability of the artwork?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to convert an Illustrator document to a PDF and make it available to graphic designers doing publicity. It would be convenient if the designers could turn off the different layers but I don't want to leave the art items editable.

Comment: Can you just Acrobat's security features? I know it's not bullet-proof but nothing is if you don't plan to rasterize and kill the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. If a PDF has layers, it is editable.

Generally Illustrator PDFs can always be edited to a degree unless the content was rasterized before saving as PDF. The ease of editing is effected by the "retain Illustrator editing" option, but that doesn't really remove any standard editing, merely complicated appearance editing.